# How can i Get Laravel relationship with its relationship values?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreign-keys, relational-database, eloquent-relationship

I have a laravel database design where every result has belongsToMany relationship with question and every question has belogsTo relationship with subject. i want to fetch subject names from results with single statement on laravel

I have tried this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through from laravel documentation

here is my code from Result model

```
public function questions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\questions', 'results_questions', 'result_id', 'questions_id');
}
```

the code from question model

```
public function subject(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subject','subject_id');
}
```

and this is what I tried from documentation (doesn't work)

```
public function subjects(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Subject',
        'App\Questions',
        'subject_id', // Foreign key on question table...
        'questions_id', // Foreign key on result table...
        'id', // Local key on question table...
        'id' // Local key on result table...
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove 5th and 6th parameters from your relation, since they are optional. Also, should your `Questions` model be lowercase?

```
public function subjects(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Subject',
        'App\questions', //*Should this be lowercase?*
        'subject_id', // Foreign key on question table...
        'questions_id', // Foreign key on result table...
    );
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.